# Using useCallback vs Moving Function Inside useEffect and Remove Dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Question is very clear as shown in title and I wonder are there any specific differences between these two different functional implementation with `useEffect`?

Here's an example:

```
  const lookAtCameraPermission = async (status: CameraPermissionStatus): Promise<void> => {
    switch (status) {
      case 'authorized':
        setIsCameraAllowed(true);
        console.log('Camera permission granted.');
        break;
      case 'not-determined':
      case 'denied':
        setIsCameraAllowed(false);
        console.log('Camera permission denied or not determined');
        await requestCameraPermission();
        break;
      default:
        setIsCameraAllowed(false);
        throw new Error('Unknown camera permission status.');
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus().then(lookAtCameraPermission).catch(console.log);
  }, [lookAtCameraPermission]);
```

When trying to implement something like this, ESLint says:
`The 'lookAtCameraPermission' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 66) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'lookAtCameraPermission' in its own useCallback() Hook.eslintreact-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

I preferred to use `useCallback` but I couldn't be sure this is the best way to implement this.

Related implementation example: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useRef` hook as an alternative way. For example:

```
const handlerRef = useRef(); 
  
handlerRef.current = async (status: CameraPermissionStatus): Promise<void> => {
    switch (status) {
      case 'authorized':
        setIsCameraAllowed(true);
        console.log('Camera permission granted.');
        break;
      case 'not-determined':
      case 'denied':
        setIsCameraAllowed(false);
        console.log('Camera permission denied or not determined');
        await requestCameraPermission();
        break;
      default:
        setIsCameraAllowed(false);
        throw new Error('Unknown camera permission status.');
    }
}; 

useEffect(() => {
 Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus().then(handlerRef.current).catch(console.log);
}, []);
```

However, I still refer the way we wrap the handler in `useCallback`, and pass it as dependencies of `useEffect`.

- The first reason is that we don't need to spend **a lot of time** thinking about what will change to put it in dependencies.
- Secondly, Make sure `useEffect` re-run when it's neccessary. If the `handler` use a variable outside of it, the `useEffect` hook should re-execute when the variable has changed.

It's terrible when we miss any item in `dependencies`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still I don't understand. The function is already existed and if I should pass it to the useEffect because re-creation of the function for each render, then I can move the function outside and can keep it static. What are benefits of useCallback or useRef here instead of static definition?

Comment: Static definition is ok in this case. But, in case your function render a component, use can not use hooks or fetch data inside of it. For example, how to call `setIsCameraAllowed` (pass it as arg, curry func?), this is what we trade-off.

Comment: It's a good point, thanks. I missed that.